# Spring Boot Adding to POST RequestBody Object but getting NULL error when adding to db

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, post

I am trying to add a unique ID to the request body of an object before writing it to the database (Apache Derby).

[PostMapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY5l1.png)

I have also tried adding the unique ID in the constructor or in the service portion. It recognizes that I have added this attribute to the object (from print statements), but when it passes to be written to the db I get the below error saying that the ID is NULL (and not the added UID string that printed).

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxwUZ.png)

I'd really appreciate any advice on how to solve this or how to better add a UID, because this has completed befuddled me. Thanks!

Edit: added screenshots of service and repo which are just plain-jane. I do not believe they are causing any errors,

Bounty service and repo:
[Bounty Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlXJK.png)
[Bounty Repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8LVe.png)

Bounty class:
[Bounty class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie2Xf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try debugging you application? Without looking at other class implementation such as BountyService and Bounty class it is difficult to help further.

Comment: yes I have tried to no avail, I added the code for service, repo, and the class itself and these are all pretty plain. Appreciate any looks.

Comment: It was the @GeneratedValue in the bounty class. Phew

Comment: nice glad you can resolve the issue by your own mate. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Needed to remove @GeneratedValue from primary key in Bounty class code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).